# Getting a MethodNotAllowedHttpException when deployed to server

Tags: laravel

When i hit submit in a form with method POST i get the `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException. No message` error.

I already checked the route and it doesn't get to the controller. This DOESN'T happen in my local environment.

`<form id="postPublish" action="/post/editPost/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

`Route::post('/post/editPost/' , 'PostController@update');`

It works locally.

Comment: are you sending the csrf token?

Comment: yes, the csrf_field is there.

Comment: maybe `php artisan route:clear` solves it

Comment: try `php artisan optimize`

Comment: and check that the request is going to the right route, and also try to use lowercase letters in the route path

Comment: I don't have ssh to that server, it's a shared hosting, so i cannot run artisan commands. Locally everything works.

Comment: create a route name and use it . `Route::post('/post/editPost/' , 'PostController@update')->name('edit.post')`  . In your form `action="{{ route('edit.post') }}"`

Comment: most shared hosting providers have ssh feature, you just need to enable it and create ssh key maybe

Comment: no, they don't, not at least here in Argentina, not shared hostings.

Comment: @grappler https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-6-removes-artisan-optimize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the final slash (both at the form's action and at the route) was the problem, `action="/posts/editPost"` worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<form id="postPublish" action="{{URL::to('post/editPost')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Route::post('post/editPost' , 'PostController@update');
```

Comment: Thanks, but te whol problem was the slash at the end of the action field and the route at the web route files.